# How to copy a file to another variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you copy a file object in Python? This is what I was trying to do:

```
inputFile = open(inputFileSpec, "rU")
inputFile2 = inputFile
```

However when I use inputFile.readline(), it also removes that same line from inputFile2. They are not actually independent copies. So, how do I got about copying inputFile where operating on either inputFile or inputFile2 will not affect the other.

Comment: Why not just `inputFile2 = open(inputFileSpec, "rU")`?

Comment: The assignment operator `=` *never* makes a copy. It only assigns the name on the left to the object on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open another copy, 
using open

otherwise you are just pointing to the same file

```
inputFile = open(inputFileSpec, "rU")
inputFile2 = open(inputFileSpec, "rU")
```

Comment: @SethMMorton I just checked, and no; it will give you a `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object`